# Copy written billion+ pixel image to Photos?

Tags: ios, macos, uiimage, phasset, photokit

My app is successfully writing multi-gigapixel images (many billions of pixels per image).

Is there a way, without reading the image as a `UIImage`, to add or copy the saved image to Photos?

It's difficult to search for the subject to find a solution that does not require `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

The issue is that the saved image is too large to load as a `UIImage` so I can't use `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

Edit: It appears that this can be done with `PhotoKit`. Can someone point me to an example of creating `PHAsset` from a saved image file? I'm currently searching.

Edit 2: Hmm seems like it is only possible to modify an existing `PHAsset` (eg an item that already exists in Photos). Which I guess would be a dead end if that is the case.

Comment: To whomever voted to have this closed: I am asking a single question. I updated the post with my findings trying to solve the question a different way that I originally posted, but the came to a dead end. Regardless, it was trying to anwer my single question which is  of-course, how do I "Copy written billion+ pixel image to Photos?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can create a new asset from a file and insert it into the user's PhotoLibrary. Take a look at `[PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL]` and the related docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetchangerequest/1624059-creationrequestforassetfromimage?language=objc

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcreationrequest?language=objc#1656303

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how I (and apparently everyone else) missed that.