# Copying/moving multi-gigabyte images with NSFileCoordinator

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, airdrop

My app is capable of writing multi-gigabyte images. I need a way to allow the user to do something with the full-resolution images (such as AirDrop). It does [not appear possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73144606/copy-written-billion-pixel-image-to-photos) to write the image to Photos or with `UIKit` since there may not be enough memory to read the whole image in RAM.

With `UIActivityViewController` I am able to copy the large images with a `NSFileCoordinator`, but only if I use an extension of `.zip` or `.bin` for the destination URL. The file is copied, but macOS thinks they are archives and not an image. After the file has been copied, changing the extension to `.jpg` on the Mac allows the copied image to be used, but that is less than an ideal user experience.

Zipping the image (that is already compressed) is not a viable solution since the whole image would need to be read to zip it, which may exceed the amount of memory available. Not to mention it is a total waste of time/power consumption.

How can I allow a user to copy multi-gigabyte images from my app, and ideally with `UIActivityViewController`?

Here is the code that allows the image to be copied. If I don't use `.zip` or `.bin` for the destination URL, the image isn't copied, nothing happens, no errors reported.

```
func copyImage() {
    
    let fm = FileManager.default
    var archiveUrl: URL?
    var error: NSError?
    let imageProductURL = TDTDeviceUtilites.getDocumentUrl(forFileName: "hugeImage.jpg")
    
    let coordinator = NSFileCoordinator()

    coordinator.coordinate(readingItemAt: imageProductURL, options: [.forUploading], error: &error) { (zipUrl) in
        let tmpUrl = try! fm.url(
            for: .itemReplacementDirectory,
            in: .userDomainMask,
            appropriateFor: zipUrl,
            create: true
        ).appendingPathComponent("hugeImage.jpg.zip")
        try! fm.moveItem(at: zipUrl, to: tmpUrl)
        archiveUrl = tmpUrl
    }

    if let archiveUrl = archiveUrl {
        let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [archiveUrl], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(avc, animated: true)
        
    } else {
        print(error)
    }
    
}
```